# Equivalence relation on class of all sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of all sets. Prove that "has the same cardinality as" defines an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{A}$.

I know that equivalence relations must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. So I think the best way to go about this would be to just show that each individual property is satisfied.... but I think I need to do more than just say hey look, this is obvious. And I am not even sure where to start.

Comment: Well, you definitely need a specific definition for "has the same cardinality," it's hard to tell from the question whether you have one in mind.

Comment: I believe the book means 'has the same cardinal number as".

Comment: If it's obvious, then you can give a short proof on-demand. If you can't, it's not obvious.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: That's just not necessarily true, when you're learning math. It's possible to understand why something is true without being certain of the formal language required to express it.

Comment: @EliRose If you cannot explain why something is true, then you don't really understand it. You may *think* you understand it, but that's it. In fact, I've found that trying to explain something to someone else (even to someone imaginary if I don't have a real person close by, or to myself in the future by taking notes) is one of the best ways to make sure I've understood something.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Prove that stuff can equal other stuff! (this is joke.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should just show that each individual property is satisfied

Reflexivity: The identity function works ($1_A: A \to A$).

Symmetry: Given $f: A \to B$ bijective, consider $f^{-1}:B \to A$.

Transitivity: Given $f: A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$, what can you say about the composition $g \circ f: A \to C$?

Answer (score 3):

Often it's difficult to tell exactly when something is supposed to be obvious. The thing to do is almost always to talk to your professor about it.

What she/he might be looking for is something on the level of bijections, which is the way we talk about two sets having the same cardinality.

So, in order to prove that this relation is:

- Reflexive -- construct a bijection from a set $A$ to itself.
- Symmetric -- given a bijection from $B \rightarrow A$, construct a bijection from $A \rightarrow B$.
- Transitive -- given a bijection from $A \rightarrow B$ and one from $B \rightarrow C$, what's the bijection from $A \rightarrow C$?